# OpenCL program build error: source file is not valid UTF-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, opencl

I have an openCL kernel that is for pathfinding in a map. This works perfectly fine on a MAC but on a windows machine, in clBuildProgram() method, I get an error stating that the source file is not valid UTF-8.

```
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename)
```

I searched online for a solution, but they are all related to clang.

I'm trying to run it on Visual Studio 2013 with NVIDIA GPU. I tried saving both .cpp and .cl files in UTF-8 format by going to File->Advanced Save Options. I also tried saving it in UTF-8 format using SublimeText 3 and still no luck.

I have other simple opencl code programs that run fine on this machine.
I tried the same on another windows PC with NVIDIA GPU and got the same error.

**main.cpp**

```
#define PROGRAM_FILE "main.cl"
#define KERNEL_FUNC "handleCall"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
using namespace std;

#define MAX_OUTPUT_BUFFER 80202

size_t worldSize, inputSize, outputSize = MAX_OUTPUT_BUFFER;
unsigned char playerId = 100;

/* Find a GPU or CPU associated with the first available platform */
cl_device_id create_device() {

    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id dev;
    int err;

    //get platform
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Access a device
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);//try GPU First
    if (err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);//CPU if GPU not found
    }
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't access any devices");
        exit(1);
    }

    return dev;
}


/* Create program from a file and compile it */
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename) {

    cl_program program;
    FILE *program_handle;
    char *program_buffer, *program_log;
    size_t program_size, log_size;
    int err;
    //Read program file and place content into buffer
    program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (program_handle == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't find the program file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(program_handle);
    rewind(program_handle);
    program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
    program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
    fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
    fclose(program_handle);

    //Create program from file
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1,
        (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
    free(program_buffer);

    //Build program
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &dev, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (err < 0) {

        //Find size of log and print to std output
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            0, NULL, &log_size);
        program_log = (char*)malloc(log_size + 1);
        program_log[log_size] = '\0';
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", program_log);
        system("pause");
        free(program_log);
        exit(1);
    }
    system("pause");
    return program;
}

unsigned char* to_bytes(unsigned short s){
    int n = 1;
    unsigned char *b = new unsigned char[2];

    // little endian if true
    if (*(char *)&n == 1) {
        b[0] = (unsigned char)(s & 0xff);
        b[1] = (unsigned char)((s >> 8) & 0xff);

    }
    else {
        b[1] = (unsigned char)(s & 0xff);
        b[0] = (unsigned char)((s >> 8) & 0xff);
    }
    return b;
}

unsigned short to_short(unsigned char lo, unsigned char hi)
{
    int n = 1;
    unsigned short x;

    // little endian if true
    if (*(char *)&n == 1) {
        x = (((int)hi) << 8) | lo;
    }
    else {
        x = (((int)lo) << 8) | hi;
    }
    return x;
}

unsigned char* getMockInputBuffer(){
    int i = 0;
    int numPlayers = 1;
    inputSize = 2 + (numPlayers * 9);
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[inputSize];

    int flag = 1;

    //Flag: 1 byte
    buffer[i++] = flag;

    //Number of Players: 1 byte
    buffer[i++] = numPlayers;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < numPlayers; iter++)
    {
        unsigned char *tempBytes;

        //PlayerID:
        buffer[i++] = playerId;

        //Source Pos x and z:
        unsigned short posX = (unsigned short)(iter + 1) * 10;
        tempBytes = to_bytes(posX);
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[0];
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[1];

        unsigned short posZ = (unsigned short)(iter + 1) * 10;
        tempBytes = to_bytes(posZ);
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[0];
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[1];

        //Send Destination
        posX = (unsigned short)(iter + 1) * 2000;
        tempBytes = to_bytes(posX);
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[0];
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[1];

        posZ = (unsigned short)(iter + 1) * 2000;
        tempBytes = to_bytes(posZ);
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[0];
        buffer[i++] = tempBytes[1];

    }

    return buffer;
}

unsigned char* getMockOutputBuffer(){
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[MAX_OUTPUT_BUFFER];
    return buffer;
}

unsigned char* getMockWorldBuffer(){

    /******** WORLD BUFFER *************/
    //Create World Buffer
    unsigned short width = 32767;
    unsigned short height = 32767;
    unsigned short xPos = 300;
    unsigned short zPos = 300;
    const unsigned short numObstacles = 7;
    unsigned short obstaclesTL[numObstacles][2] = { { 0, 10 }, { 500, 500 }, { 400, 6000 }, { 10, 10 }, { 0, 0 }, { 300, 10 }, { 300, 6001 } };
    unsigned short obstacleBR[numObstacles][2] = { { 20, 20 }, { 600, 600 }, { 600, 7000 }, { 900, 7000 }, { 200, 200 }, { 1000, 6000 }, { 30000, 6005 } };

    int i = 0;
    worldSize = (sizeof(unsigned short) * 7 * 4) + 13; // since we have 13 obstacles with xmin,xmax,zmin,zmax coordinates
    unsigned char * worldBytes = new unsigned char[worldSize];
    unsigned char * widthVal = to_bytes(width); //width pos 0-1
    unsigned char * heightVal = to_bytes(height); //height byte 2-3

    worldBytes[i++] = widthVal[0];
    worldBytes[i++] = widthVal[1];
    worldBytes[i++] = heightVal[0];
    worldBytes[i++] = heightVal[1];

    unsigned char n_players = 1;
    worldBytes[i++] = n_players;

    for (int iter = 0; iter < n_players; iter++)
    {
        //Send PlayerID
        //char PlayerID = IDArray[iter];
        worldBytes[i++] = playerId + 1;

        //Send Postions
        unsigned char * playerSourceX = to_bytes(xPos);
        unsigned char * playerSourceZ = to_bytes(zPos);
        worldBytes[i++] = playerSourceX[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = playerSourceX[1];
        worldBytes[i++] = playerSourceZ[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = playerSourceZ[1];
    }

    /*******  Obstacles   *******/
    unsigned char * m_ObstaclesArray = to_bytes(numObstacles);
    worldBytes[i++] = m_ObstaclesArray[0];

    for (int k = 0; k < numObstacles; k++)
    {
        unsigned char * tl_x = to_bytes(obstaclesTL[k][0]);
        unsigned char * tl_z = to_bytes(obstaclesTL[k][1]);
        unsigned char * br_x = to_bytes(obstacleBR[k][0]);
        unsigned char * br_z = to_bytes(obstacleBR[k][1]);
        worldBytes[i++] = tl_x[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = tl_x[1];
        worldBytes[i++] = tl_z[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = tl_z[1];
        worldBytes[i++] = br_x[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = br_x[1];
        worldBytes[i++] = br_z[0];
        worldBytes[i++] = br_z[1];
    }

    return worldBytes;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int err;
    ofstream file("output.txt");
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    //OpenCL structures
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    size_t local_size, global_size;
    size_t num_groups;

    unsigned char *world = getMockWorldBuffer();
    unsigned char *input = getMockInputBuffer();
    unsigned char *output = getMockOutputBuffer();

    //Create data buffer
    global_size = 2;
    local_size = 1;
    num_groups = global_size / local_size;

    //Data and buffers
    cl_mem worldBuffer, inputBuffer, outputBuffer;
    //Create device and context
    device = create_device();
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create context");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Build program
    program = build_program(context, device, PROGRAM_FILE);

    //Create buffs
    if (program == NULL) {
        perror("could not create program");
        exit(1);
    }

    worldBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, worldSize, world, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create world buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, inputSize, input, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create input buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, outputSize, output, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create output buffer");
        exit(1);
    }


    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Create a kernel
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_FUNC, &err);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not create kernel");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Set kernel arguments
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &worldBuffer);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not set world kernel args");
        exit(1);
    }

    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputBuffer);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not set input kernel args");
        exit(1);
    }

    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &outputBuffer);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not set output kernel args");
        exit(1);
    }

    cl_event event;

    //Enqueue kernel
    clRetainMemObject(outputBuffer);
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size,
        0, 0, NULL, &event);
    if (err<0) {
        perror("could not enqueue kernel");
        exit(1);
    }

    clWaitForEvents(1, &event);

    cl_ulong time_start, time_end;
    double total_time;

    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
    total_time = time_end - time_start;
    printf("\nExecution time in milliseconds = %0.3f ms\n", (total_time / 1000000.0));

    //Read the kernel's output
    unsigned char *testOutputBuffer = new unsigned char[MAX_OUTPUT_BUFFER];

    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0,
        MAX_OUTPUT_BUFFER, testOutputBuffer, 0, NULL, &event);

    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        perror("could not read from kernel");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Reading Result Buffer:
    //Flag: 0(PlayerData) or 1(Path):
    //Number of players(1 byte)
    //PLayerID(1byte) (n-times)
    //m set of coords (2bytes) (PathReq only)
    //posX (2bytes) (PlayerData: Last known Position         PathReq:Position in the path )
    //posZ (2bytes) (PlayerData: Last known Position         PathReq:Position in the path )

    //For Path Req its      2bytes + n*(PlayerID + 2+ (m*4) )
    //For Player Data its   2bytes + n*(PlayerID + (m*4) )

    cout << "Flag = " << (short)testOutputBuffer[0] << "\n";
    cout << "Num players = " << (short)testOutputBuffer[1] << "\n";
    cout << "Player ID = " << (short)testOutputBuffer[2] << "\n";
    cout << "Num Turns = " << (short)testOutputBuffer[3] << "\n";

    short m = (short)testOutputBuffer[3];
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 4; i < m * 4 + 4; i += 4){
        short x = to_short(testOutputBuffer[i], testOutputBuffer[i + 1]);
        short z = to_short(testOutputBuffer[i + 2], testOutputBuffer[i + 3]);
        cout << "Turns " << j++ << " = (" << x << "," << z << ") \n";
    }


    file << "\nExecution time in milliseconds = " << (total_time / 1000000.0) << "ms\n";
    printf("finished\n");
    file.close();
    //Cleanup
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseMemObject(worldBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(inputBuffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(outputBuffer);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseContext(context);
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cl:**
[google drive link to main.cl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxiBPteJoxRgUEQ2cHE0QmYtTVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you try to indent or pretty print your code with `astyle`  ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, no i did not. To check if it was something with the encoding on Mac, I even created a new file in sublimetext in my PC and copy pasted just the code to it, and still no luck.

Comment: @Zoso, It seems your main.cl file has no issues, it looks to be fine. I took your main.cl and used it to compile in my opencl based application. It didn't throw any compilation errors (I am getting a different error though i.e., "Error:E013:Insufficient Private Resources!"). FYI, I am using VS2013 on windows 8.1. The target platform is Kaveri based AMD-GPU

Answer (score 5):

you should open your kernel file in binary mode not in text mode.
instead of using
`program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");`, you should use `program_handle = fopen(filename, "rb");`

the problem is due to conversion between UNIX and windows text styles, windows counts end of line as 2 characters \n\r, if you don't open your file in binary mode you will end up with strange characters at the end of your buffer when you use `fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

For some reason, it was solved by using fstream object to read the .cl file into a char array.

Try changing the lines

```
    FILE *program_handle;
    char *program_buffer, *program_log;
    size_t program_size, log_size;
    int err;
    //Read program file and place content into buffer
    program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (program_handle == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't find the program file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(program_handle);
    rewind(program_handle);
    program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
    program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
    fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
    fclose(program_handle);
```

with something like:

```
std::fstream kernelFile(filename);
    std::string content(
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(kernelFile)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
        );

    const char* kernelCharArray = new char[content.size()];
    kernelCharArray = content.c_str();
```

Comment: It works for me. Thanks! Just curious, can you explain why it works?